# Array in Mips Assembly with looping

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, mips

I am having an issue with my code. I am creating a program that will read in a string, save it into an array and then output the number of times each letter is used in the string. For right now I am having an issue with just the output of the string back to the screen. The string is outputted but the loop never exits, the $t2 value is maybe never set to a value?

```
.data
intro: .asciiz "Andrew Lofgren, Letter Checker Program" 
question: .asciiz "\nPlease enter a string for evaluation: "
alphabet: .ascii "ABCDEFGHIJKLMONOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
results: .space 104
string: .space 1024

.text 

main:
jal setup
jal analyze
#jal results

li  $v0, 10
syscall 

setup:
li  $v0, 4  # outputing name and program information
la  $a0, intro
syscall

li  $v0, 4  # asksing for string input
la  $a0, question
syscall 

li  $v0, 8
la  $a0, string
li  $a1, 1024
syscall

jr  $ra     # return

analyze: 
la  $t0, string # taking string and saving into a tmp
move    $t2, $t0    # backup of orignal address
find:   
beq $t1, 0, print
addi    $t0, $t0, 1
j find

print:  
blt $t0, $t2, end   #PROBLEM HERE
li  $v0, 11
lb  $a0, 0($t0)
syscall
addi    $t0, $t0, 1
j print
end:
jr  $ra
```

Comment: Your exit-condition is that t0<t2, yet you're _incrementing_ t0 at the end of each iteration. That doesn't quite add up, unless you've got a very, _very_ long string.

Answer (score 1):

`$t0` will never be less than `$t2`, because `$t0` continually increases while `$t2` remains the same. To solve this, you need a third register, say `$t7`, which stores the final index of your string. To calculate the last index, simply add the base address of the string to length which you have defined as 1024. Once `$t0` is no longer less than 1024 + string, there are no chars left in the string, and thus we branch to `end:`. This is done and explained further in the code segment below.

```
print:
    li      $t7 , 1024            # Load total byte length of the string
    add     $t7 , $t7 , $t2     # add it to the base address to get the end
    slt     $t6 , $t0 , $t7     # check to see if cur index < end
    beq     $t6 , $0 , end     # if we hit the end, branch to end

...
```

For more information on MIPS instructions, [visit this page](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).